# Controlling vertical rules in NiceTabular (NiceMatrix)

Tags: nicematrix

Is there a way to have finer-grained control of vertical rules (along the lines of what `cline` permits for horizontal rules) in a `NiceTabular` environment?

E.g., I would like to eliminate the vertical line between "Semantic" and "Substantive" on the top right:

[image]

In a regular tabular environment, I would just use two multicolumn commands like `\multicolumn{1}{l}{Semantic} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Substantive}`. Is there any way to replicate this in the NiceMatrix NiceTabular environment? MWE:

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
&& \Block{1-2}{Subject}&\\
&& \textbf{Semantic} & \textbf{Substantive} \\
\cline{3-4}
\Block{2-1}{Justification} & \textbf{Semantic} & Surplusage & Common law \\
\cline{3-4}
& \textbf{Substantive} & Whole code & Lenity
\end{NiceTabular}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an empty block which will prevent the vertical rule in the second row (the command `\Block{1-2}{}` below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
&& \Block{1-2}{Subject}&\\
&& \Block{1-2}{}\textbf{Semantic} & \textbf{Substantive} \\
\cline{3-4}
\Block{2-1}{Justification} & \textbf{Semantic} & Surplusage & Common law \\
\cline{3-4}
& \textbf{Substantive} & Whole code & Lenity
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

You can also add the vertical rule as a border of an empty block (the command `\Block[borders=right]{2-1}{}` below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}}
&& \Block{1-2}{Subject}&\\
&& \textbf{Semantic} & \textbf{Substantive} \\
\cline{3-4}
\Block{2-1}{Justification} & \textbf{Semantic} & 
\Block[borders=right]{2-1}{}
Surplusage & Common law \\
\cline{3-4}
& \textbf{Substantive} & Whole code & Lenity
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is not exactly the same because, now, the rule is drawn after the construction of the array and no space is reserved for the vertical rule between the columns (3 & 4). Of course, that's only a difference of 0.4 pt.

[image: Output of the second code]

You can also draw with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter`: `\CodeAfter \tikz \draw (3-|4) -- (last-|4);` (of course this technic requires a minimal knowledge of Tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}}
&& \Block{1-2}{Subject}&\\
&& \textbf{Semantic} & \textbf{Substantive} \\
\cline{3-4}
\Block{2-1}{Justification} & \textbf{Semantic} & 
Surplusage & Common law \\
\cline{3-4}
& \textbf{Substantive} & Whole code & Lenity 
\CodeAfter \tikz \draw (3-|4) -- (last-|4) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.